# Laravel error in exception handler

Tags: php, laravel-4

I've installed laravel 4 and when I go to the following URL:

```
http://localhost/laravel/public/
```

I got this error:

```
Error in exception handler.
```

I've tried so far like said in this topic

[Error in exception handler. - Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186952/error-in-exception-handler-laravel)

but it couldn't help me. Any ideas?

Comment: What's your OS? Also set `app/config/local/app.php` `debug` to `true` and paste the full error message.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04. Here is an error after changing false to true: Error in exception handler: The stream or file "/var/www/html/laravel/app/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/laravel/bootstrap/compiled.php:8788

Comment: Make sure you add write permissions to the storage directory.

Comment: my app/storage has following permissions: drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Try `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/laravel/app/storage/`

Comment: Rahil Wazir, Awesome. Works like a charm. You made my day!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel needs to write some files to app/storage folder so give app/storage write permissions chmod 777 some thing as suggested as below url or use chown www-data:www-data -R app/storage

[Laravel error](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8923)

Comment: my app/storage has following permissions: drwxrwxr-x

Answer (score 1):

Were you using the FTP (FileZilla) ssh root@ipaddress and trying to connect the web server and does not see the var/www/html on list? you might thought it was just chmod -R 777(laravel's group folder)/app/storage, so I decided try by this  sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(laravel's group folder)/app/storage. check the web server it went through the permission and it works.

Answer (score 1):

@ArunKumar is right. But I generally use the artisan with sudo. This will give artisan all the permissions it needs and won't make any security problems as well.

so instead starting artisan serve with:

```
$ php artisan serve
```

try using:

```
$ sudo php artisan serve
```

thus you wont have to make any permission changes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permission error,

Go to your Project folder path were it is located.

```
eg:- cd /var/www/html/project-folder/
```

Then type,

```
chmod -R 777 project-folder
```

press Enter, That's it..