# Laravel 5 Ubuntu Blade not rendered

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

I'm trying to set up Laravel 5 With ubuntu 14.04 and Parallels plesk.
I have setup  laravel via composer and when i browse my.domain.co it shows white page. Default welcome page is not rendered.

I've  setup a test route

```
Route::get('/hello', function(){ return 'hello';});
```

When i browse my.domain.com.co/hello it shows hello string.

Blade templates are not rendered. Why?

Edit: Folder permissions was the issue.

[This post solves my issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186952/error-in-exception-handler-laravel)

Comment: Take a look at your web server's error logs

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the web server has write permission to the storage directory.

Comment: Thanks, indeed permissions was the issue.

Comment: Had the same issue thanks!