# Error in exception handler in Apache/2.4.16

Tags: macos, apache, laravel, exception

I am trying to setup local dev env on `Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5`, and with `Apache` server version

> Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) Server built:   Jul 22 2015
>   21:03:09

When I use localhost as `URL`(Removed `index.html`), I get this error

> Error in exception handler

I tried debugging this but could not find a solution.

I also tried changing the `httpd.conf` file, still didn't get fixed.

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I want to see folder structure in the browser.

Comment: Are you trying to setup laravel?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to install Laravel. But Laravel has different issue. I have different folder structure for Laravel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in exception handler. - Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186952/error-in-exception-handler-laravel)

Comment: Now that I have solved the above mentioned issue, I am still facing another issue. When I try to manually give url for eg  `http://localhost/laravel/public` I get `Error in exception handler.` where as when I use vhost I get `PDOException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Operation timed out`.

Comment: here is virtual host `<VirtualHost admin.local:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/branch/enterprise/public"
        ServerName admin.local
        ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/admin.local-error_log"
        CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/admin.local-access_log" common

        <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/branch/enterprise/public">
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Put extra info in the question itself. Click [edit].